# Claimed share of something

Tags: grammar

Why is it wrong to say claim share of something ?

Here is a sentence, the book recommended correct it :

> - He claimed his share of a booty.

---

Three books or more mentioned as  : He claimed his half share of the booty.

As I know logically, the booty should be divided equally or in any way the members agreed in advance. For examples in case of theft or during wars in ancient time.

I think grammatically, there is no error.

Hmm, some dictionaries tell the word booty is both countable and uncountable. Others, would tell = uncountable only.

Of course, if the word ( booty) = uncountable then the indefinite article is not used.
The matter why I astonished; they all ( add half before the word share - half share)

Comment: It isn't wrong. They probably want you to change **a** to **the booty**. I note that you have used _the_ in your own sentence.

Comment: @Kate Bunting  thank you  Here is    He claimed his half share of the booty.    ( using the ) I agree with you  But they all add the word ( half )   3 books or more than three

Comment: What books?? A quick google finds this phrase in "Wren and Martin" -- if so, the garbage is your only option.  Wren & Martin needs to be consigned to history as soon as possible please.

Comment: Yes, one of these books is  Wren & Martin   But the book from which I brought the sentence is not  Wren & Martin  but another book ( Academic Grammar and Composition-VIII - Page 46 )  It is also mentioned in English for Competitive Examinations:   revised version \ Wren & Martin

Comment: Yes, they are all the same source.  One book is just copying examples from another.  Wren & Martin is the single source of this line. It's not several people using the same expression, it's just one example.  It's easy to find examples which don't have the word "half"...  Wren and Martin is a particularly bad book.  It is not suitable for a learner of English. The grammar explanations are incorrect, and the examples and style are 1930s Anglo-Indian, and often not idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

There is no error in "his share of the booty".

You could, I suppose, modify this to "half share of the booty" if a person is indeed taking half, but it's rather less common. Booty may be shared in any ratio, not just 50-50. It doesn't have to be shared equally, indeed typically the boss gets the "lion's share".

I suggest not using a grammar book that indicates that "half" is required.

Comment: Then the indefinite article is not used , is it ?

Comment: No, nor is it used in the grammar book.  I'm assuming that's just a typo.  But you would use "a" in the normal way, if "booty" isn't determined.

Comment: But by the time you come to sharing a booty, it is normally clear to everyone which booty you are sharing, so "the" is most likely determiner.

Comment: It's very rare to say "a booty" when referring to treasure; you almost always talk about "the booty", meaning whatever the pirates have previously captured. "Booty" isn't used much outside specific expressions (except with other meanings, like a small boot.)

Comment: More to the point, _booty_ is a mass noun. You can have _the_ booty_, _some booty_, _lots of booty_, but you can't have _a booty_, or _a few booty_.

Comment: Actually I'd disagree with "you can't have a booty": "The pirates hid a booty in the old well and another in a cave." As a countable noun it means "a collection of booty"  But it's a rare enough word that the countable form would be very very rare (and hard to search for because it also means "butt" in kid slang and that is certainly countable.)  The non-count form is much more common.